# python import as equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, python

I have a bunch of idl files that automatically create four packages, with a lot of java files into it. 
I need to insert those java files in a com.bla. package architecture.

Thing is in my generated files I have imports UCO.State for example, that do not fit with my new package architecture.

So question is : Is there a java equivalent to 'import com.bla as bla' ?

The only other option I see is to import the UCO package and rename all UCO.State and other directly by State. 
But that would mean refactoring hundreds of files o_O.

Any idea ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, lying in the documentation of my idlj generation tool.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi-iiop/toJavaPortableUG.html

You should search for information in the pkgTranslate and pkgPrefix options :)
This way, the tool automatically changes foo => com.bla.foo

Problem solved !

Answer (score 0):

Import all the files in Eclipse. If you manage to get the code compile using the refactor functions of the IDE it will save you all the trouble.

There is no functionality of adding synonyms to the imports in java, but even if there was such how would that have helped you? You still will need to change all your files.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the fast answer. I want to avoid refactoring because if for any reason I have to regenerate later, all would have to be done again.